# How To Reload Table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 views we are dealing with.  Main View, and Sub View.

Main View's tablecell's string shows the count of the number of objects in that cell's subView.  When I delete a cell from the subview, and go back to the mainView, the string that shows the count should go down by 1.  Right now this string is not changing until I restart the app.

Any ideas how I can fix this?  The count is being pulled from a NSFetch.

Edit: Added Code

```
- (void)configureCell:(TDBadgedCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
    NSDate *thisWeek  = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -604800.0];
    NSDate *thisMonth = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -2629743.83];
    else if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        self.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(timeStamp >= %@) AND (timeStamp <= %@)", thisWeek, today];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);

        cell.badgeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [results count]];
        [fetchRequest release];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        self.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(timeStamp >= %@) AND (timeStamp <= %@)", thisMonth, today];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);

        cell.badgeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [results count]];
        [fetchRequest release];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        cell.badgeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is in fact being updated correctly on the model side of things, you should be able to call

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

and everything will update correctly. You can probably put this in viewWillAppear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that but no luck.  It does update correctly when I restart the app though so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: The string I am trying to update is the TDBadgeCell String attribute (https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell) if that matters.

Comment: Is there some data that your app saves out when it quits or resigns as the active application? Have you checked your model after you update it to see that the data is getting over to your main view?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it saves properly, because when I select the given row from the main view, the subtable has the correct data depending on if I added/deleted a cell.  It just the count on the mainView that isn't updating until I restart the app.

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in your main view where it gets the count of your data container and see if it is being updated or even being called for that matter.

Comment: Hey Jamie, ill try that.  But I'm also going to post the cellForIndexRowData and maybe you can see anything that may be wrong.

Comment: Here is a link to a post on how to refetch your data model. I think this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399012/nsfetchedresultscontroller-refresh-refetch

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that you're getting the proper handle on the tableview, if you've made an accessor for your tableview in the header file then you need to call it by that name in the viewWillLoad method.