# Refresh entire NSFetchedResultsController tableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, refresh, nsmanagedobject

I'm using `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` to refresh a single cell in my Core Data `tableView` by getting the `indexPath` for that cell. Is it possible to refresh the entire `tableView` instead of that single cell? I've only found that `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` works for what I need to do.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399012/nsfetchedresultscontroller-refresh-refetch

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for.

Comment: No, I need a way to refresh all of the instances of my NSManagedObject. I can refresh a single object by getting its indexPath, but I can't figure out a way to do it to everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refetch your data.

There is a property, `setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects` that ensures fetch requests go down to the store.

setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:
Sets whether the fetch request should cause property values of fetched objects to be updated with the current values in the persistent store.

> **- (void)setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:(BOOL)flag**
>
> **Parameters**
>
> flag YES if the fetch request should cause property values of fetched
>   objects to be updated with the current values in the persistent store,
>   otherwise NO
>
> **Discussion**
>
> By default, when you fetch objects they
>   maintain their current property values, even if the values in the
>   persistent store have changed. By invoking this method with the
>   parameter YES, when the fetch is executed the property values of
>   fetched objects to be updated with the current values in the
>   persistent store. This provides more convenient way to ensure managed
>   object property values are consistent with the store than by using
>   refreshObject:mergeChanges: (NSManagedObjetContext) for multiple
>   objects in turn.