# Filtering a hardcoded tableview products database e.g. narrow by price

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a small database with 4 fields: Title, Price, Camera (Y/N) and Photo.

it is an app displaying a list of products in a UITableView and a DetailedView for each.

Now what I want to do is add another ViewController that will contain a Slider (for Price) and a Segmented Controler (for Camera, so if the product has camera Yes or No). Apply button at the bottom.

The user should be able to go to this ViewController, and set a price of $50 for example and after pressing Apply, the app would take them back to a UITableView showing only prducts that cost less than $50.

If the user chooses to filter by camera, they should be able to as well, using the segmented controller.

Any ideas how I could go on about doing this, and if there are any tutorials available? The only tutorials on filtering I could find are about adding a search bar but that is NOT what I want to do.

I am using the following code to display my content into the table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    cell.PriceLabel.text = _Price[row];
    cell.CompanyLabel.text = _Company[row];
    cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
    cell.CameraLabel.text = _Camera[row];
```

I guess this is all really basic. Is there a way of doing the filtering like this or would I have to learn core data?

My data is stored in TableViewController.m in the following format:

```
_Title = @[@"180 QX HD",
               @"200 QX",
               @"350 QX RTF",
```

etc and

```
 _Price = @[@"189",
              @"229",
              @"420",
```

Comment: Your question is very broad.  Have you started to carrying out any portions of this flow at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Core-Data database you will probably find answer for your question here [Applying a filter to NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15370594/3725806).
If not you have to post more info and some code.

Answer (score 0):

have two NSMutableArrays :

1. The array that has ALL results in it (allResultsArray)
2. The array that has FILTERED results in it (filteredResultsArray)

filteredResultsArray is initially filled with allResultsArray and then based on all your filter controlls etc, only relevant results remain in it.

You will need to create functions that modify filteredResultsArray based on your filters.

Your UITableView should only reference filteredResultsArray in all it's delegate functions.
reload the table whenever filteredResultsArray has changed

Comment: So I am not currently using an Array, I am using the following to display my content (I have added my original post).

Comment: I think you should create a result object that has all the information for an item in it, have an array (as in my answer) holding these objects, and load cells with these objects rather then by referencing the index of different arrays for each component as you do.